# Laravel validation: rules in required_if

Tags: php, laravel

I have a select list, where the first option is disabled, that's way when the user does not choose an valid option, the result of the select list will not be in the request.

In the validation, the field required, if the value of an other field is for example : `1, in case not 1, the field is not required`.

The code:

```
'city_id' => [
'required',
'integer',
Rule::in(City::availableCities()),
],
'district_id' => new DistrictValidation(request('city_id')),
```

How I can do that, the `district_id` throw the validation every time,  regardless of, it is in the request, or not.

Thanks for answers,

Update:
Maybe you see clearly, if the DistrictValidation rule is here:

```
class DistrictValidation implements Rule
{
    protected $city;
    private $messages;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @param $cityId
     */
    public function __construct($cityId)
    {
        $this->city = City::find($cityId);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        dd('here');
        if (!$this->city) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!$this->city->hasDistrict) {
            return true;
        }

        $validator = Validator::make([$attribute => $value], [
            $attribute => [
                'required',
                'integer',
                Rule::in(District::availableDistricts()),
            ]
        ]);

        $this->messages = $validator->messages();

        return $validator->passes();
    }
    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
       return optional($this->messages)->first('district_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your full validation code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `required_if` condition defined in laravel validation
Here is the link to the proper documentaion [Laravel Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation)

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'city_id' => [
        'required',
        'integer',
        Rule::in(City::availableCities()),
    ],
    'district_id'=>[
         'required_with:city_id,',
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand this.
If you thought about 'required_if:city_id == 1', it is ok, it's work, but I would not like this.
I think something like that:
'required_id:city_id = new DistrictValidation... but, of course, it does not work...

Comment: "Validation rule required_if requires at least 2 parameters."

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand yet, how does the districtValidation rule run?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'city_id' => [
  'nullable',
  'numeric',
  Rule::in(City::availableCities())
],
'district_id' => new DistrictValidation(request('city_id')),
```

Comment: @LaszloP read docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$myValidations = [
    "city_id" => [
        "required",
        "integer"
    ]
]

// if city_id exists in availableCities so add some rules 
if(collect(city::availableCities)->contains(request("city_id"))){
    $myValidations["district_id"] = new DistrictValidation(request('city_id'))
}

// validate request fields with $myValidations variable
```

Comment: Ok, but if the 'district_id' non exist in the request, the validation will not happen.

Comment: @LaszloP why ?  If I meant you right you want to validate district_id if city_id exists in availableCities

Comment: No. What I would like:
For example if the city_id = 1, then the district_id => 'required',
if the city_id = 2, then the district_id => 'nullable'

Answer (score 0):

try using the `required_if` validation where the field under validation must be present and not empty if the anotherfield field is equal to any value.

```
required_if:field,value,...
```

use it like:

`$request->validate([
    'city_id' => 'required|integer|Rule::in(City::availableCities())',
    'district_id' => 'required_if:city_id,1',
]);`

try to read more laravel validation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation)

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.